# React-native app after eas build not working

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I've been developing a react-native app using expo, where you need to make login to then access the rest of the app, the rest includes a bottomTabNavigator with a home, tournaments, checkIn, support, and profile screens. This all work when using `npx expo start` just for development with metro, BUT when I run `eas build --platform android` and the app is built has an .apk and installed on my phone I get the login screen but neither the splash screen, icon nor the screen after the login are working. Can it be any problem from expo? or react-native?

I've already tried to clear cache on build with `eas build --platform --clear-cache`.